# How to get started with program synthesis

Tags: reference-request, pl.programming-languages

I am a CS Major, I am a programmer with 10 years of experience. i want to get to know about program synthesis. there are no video tutorials / courses available online. 
i have researched about Emina Torlak, Ras Bodik, who offer courses here https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse507/14au/sched.html

Any pointers / materials ?

Comment: I'm on the fence about this question. On one hand, it is a basic question, on the other there are some very popular questions on mathoverflow of the same bent: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18794/how-to-start-game-theory https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1291/a-learning-roadmap-for-algebraic-geometry/1378 https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83869/getting-started-combinatorial-optimization-for-computer-scientists/83927 Do we really want to disallow these types of questions?

Comment: What's wrong with just moving it over to CS.SE?

Comment: Either is fine, but I think questions of the style "what is a roadmap for learning X", where X is a field of computer science, should be on-topic here, as they are on mathoverflow.

Comment: @cypher You might be interested in the Rosette language: https://emina.github.io/rosette/